# Which Magento table to check for custom customer attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added a new custom customer attribute as below in an installer script:

```
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'organisation_id', array('type' => 'int'));
```

Can someone confirm which table I can find this new 'organisation_id' column within the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `eav_attribute` table you can find your `organisation_id`.

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I have deleted the customer attribute  from  table now its not creating again using script